# Error in grabbing Grapes - Dependency not found

Tags: grails, groovy, dependencies, httpclient, httpbuilder

I have a Groovy file having following code :

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7' )
```

I am trying to download the dependencies to use `HTTPBuilder`.

But it's showing me the error as follows :

> Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1!httpclient.jar,download failed: org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.1!httpcore.jar, download failed: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6!commons-codec.jar, download failed: commons-beanutils#commons-beanutils;1.8.0!commons-beanutils.jar, download failed: commons-lang#commons-lang;2.4!commons-lang.jar]

I tried resolving this Grape dependency using below command in command prompt :

```
grape resolve org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder http-builder 0.7.2
```

I also tried the below one too :

```
grape install org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder http-builder 0.7.2
```

then also it is showing me the same error. How can I solve this problem? I use Groovy version 2.2.2.

Comment: I tried grabbing another randomly chosen dependency :

`@Grab(group='org.springframework', module='spring', version='2.5.6')`

even this is also failing to download ...

Comment: I think no any dependency is being added using **@Grab** annotation ...

Comment: have you looked into other questions with the same problem first? e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871792/groovy-grab-download-failed

Comment: Kudos to you cfrick .. You solved my problem of getting the dependency onto my system(SUCCESSFULLY COMPILED).
But in runtime my `.groovy` file, it's saying 
`NoClassDefFound` error for `HTTPBuilder` class..

Even when I am having all the dependencies needed.

Can you please do me one more favour.

Comment: Solved my problem.

I deleted `grapes` folder present in `.groovy` folder(in user's root directory) and Again compiled my `script.groovy` file..

Many many thnx to you @cfrick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From cfrick's referred link(as mentioned in comment),

I created grapeConfig.xml as mentioned in accepted answer of the link ([Groovy - Grab - download failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871792/groovy-grab-download-failed))

and successfully able to get all the dependencies to my system.
That's what I was looking for.