# Intellij Groovy Compiler throws error Grabbing Grapes (download failed)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, compiler-errors

I'm currently getting the following error when I try to compile my **groovy** project in Intellij IDEA 15.0.3 on Mac OSX 10.10.5. (This issue is not occurring for the same project on a Windows machine)

> **Information:Groovyc: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed:
>   com.google.code.gson#gson;2.2.4!gson.jar]**

The JAR exists in [repo.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.gson%7Cgson%7C2.2.4%7Cjar) and in [jcenter.bintray.com](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.google.code.gson%3Agson/2.2.4/view#files/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4).

I can download and include it in my project explicitly using `compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4"` - I still see this compiler issue.

I can't see any reason why the download would fail, I'm using the [out-of-the-box `~/.gradle/grapeConfig.xml`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-groovy/blob/master/src/resources/groovy/grape/defaultGrapeConfig.xml).

I've tried deleting my grapes cache directory and re-downloading dependencies - works for all my explicitly defined dependencies.

I'm on a home network - no proxy.

I want to [enable advanced logging](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html#Grape-Logging), so that I can see the exact reason why the Grapes download is failing. I've tried adding the `groovy.grape.report.downloads=true` system property to the terminal (and in `~/.bashrc`), but to no avail. I couldn't find any way of setting these properties in the Intellij "Groovy Compiler" settings page. **(If I could enable Grapes logging, I'm confident I'd be able to see the root cause)**

The Intellij project is setup from `gradle cleanIdea idea`. When the project is built from the command line - `gradle clean build` (on Mac and Windows), the application compiles with no errors - only problem is in Intellij on a Mac.

This `gson.jar` isn't actually referenced in any `@Grab`/`@Grape` annotations, I haven't checked but I'm guessing it's a transitive dependency.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

### Full Stack Trace

```
Information:Using javac 1.8.0_60 to compile java sources
Information:Groovyc: Groovyc stub generation failed
Information:Groovyc: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: com.google.code.gson#gson;2.2.4!gson.jar]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.getDependencies(GrapeIvy.groovy:421)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.resolve(GrapeIvy.groovy:566)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy$resolve$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.resolve(GrapeIvy.groovy:535)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy$resolve$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.grab(GrapeIvy.groovy:257)
    at groovy.grape.Grape.grab(Grape.java:166)
    at groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation.visit(GrabAnnotationTransformation.java:360)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:321)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:931)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:593)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovyCompilerWrapper.compile(GroovyCompilerWrapper.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.DependentGroovycRunner.runGroovyc(DependentGroovycRunner.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner.intMain2(GroovycRunner.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.runGroovycInThisProcess(InProcessGroovyc.java:156)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.access$000(InProcessGroovyc.java:51)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc$1.call(InProcessGroovyc.java:85)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc$1.call(InProcessGroovyc.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'server'
Information:12/02/2016 6:45 PM - Compilation completed with 3 errors and 0 warnings in 9s 266ms
/<myproject>/WebConfigurer.java
Error:(10, 37) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HtmlHttpMessageConverter
  location: package mypackage.mediaType
Error:(113, 16) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HtmlHttpMessageConverter
  location: class mypackage.WebConfigurer
/<myproject>/SirenConverters.java
Error:(14, 38) java: package mypackage.controller does not exist
```

### Related(?)

[Groovy - Grab - download failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871792/groovy-grab-download-failed)

### *Update 14/02/16 - still no luck*

1. Moved grapeConfig.xml to correct directory - `~/.groovy/grapeConfig.xml`
2. Enabled debug logging in Intellij:

   ...
   <root>
     <priority value="DEBUG"/>
     <appender-ref ref="DIALOG"/>
     <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE-DEBUG"/>
     <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
   </root>
   ...

No further details about exception found in `~/Library/Logs/IdeaIC15/idea.log`

3. Added logging flag to `/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 15\ CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions`

   -Dgroovy.grape.report.downloads=true
   -Xms128m
   -Xmx750m
   -XX:MaxPermSize=350m
   -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
   -XX:+UseCompressedOops

No observable change in the logs or console.

4. Added `-Dgroovy.grape.report.downloads=true` to Intellij Preferences > Compiler > Shared build process VM options:

No observable change in the logs or console.

Comment: I resolved similar by specifying `org.apache.ivy` as a Maven dependency in my pom.xml file using the lines found at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ivy/ivy/2.4.0

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and for me it was the maven cache that was the problem.

I found the solution [on this page](https://github.com/alan-morey/force-meta-backup/issues/29):

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository ~/.groovy/grapes
```

I had previously tried removing the `~/.groovy/grapes` cache, but that didn't fix the problem. Removing the `~/.m2/repository` is what actually did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got this script working in IntelliJ without problem:

```
@Grab(group = 'com.google.code.gson', module = 'gson', version = '2.2.4')
import com.google.gson.Gson

println Gson
```

First thing I did was to write the @Grab declaration... right-click on it, select "Grab artifacts"...

**EDIT**: Actually, I think put the cursor on @Grab, then pushed Alt+Enter (which is what I usually do to get suggestions from IntelliJ).

IntelliJ failed and told me I need to add Ivy to the classpath... so I opened Project Structure, in Module dependencies added Ivy, tried again... it worked.

Running the script again, it printed the expected message.

Hope that helps somehow...

Comment: No luck unfortunately, still receiving the following message. Good suggestion though. `0 Grape dependency jars added
@Grab(group = 'com.google.code.gson', module = 'gson', version = '2.2.4'): 0 jars Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: com.google.code.gson#gson;2.2.4!gson.jar] `

Comment: Well, given that the only possible difference between yours and mine environment is the Ivy configuration, I suggest you try to completely clean up your ".groovy/grapes" directory and remove the ivy config file. There's just no reason why it shouldn't work for you.